# Oracle RMAN encryption

Tags: oracle, security, encryption, rman

I would like to know if it is possible given a certain backup made with RMAN in Oracle 12c is encrypted without having to restore said backup, is there any or some queries that verify if an RMAN backup is encrypted or not?

To launch the backup I use the option SET ENCRYPTION ON IDENTIFIED BY qazwsx ONLY;

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using an RMAN Catalog server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can query V$BACKUP_PIECE in target database or RC_BACKUP_PIECE in RMAN catalog:

```
SQL> select encrypted, tag from v$backup_piece;

ENC TAG
--- --------------------------------
NO  TAG20180926T211157
NO  TAG20180926T211159
YES TAG20180926T211224
YES TAG20180926T211227
```